# repeat same test for a number of functions

Tags: python, pytest, repeat

I am writing a database client and want to make sure the logging and retry mechanism is working for all of my CRUD methods.

Is there a way to repeat the same test over and over again for all methods in a list?

Or what would be best practice here?

```
    @patch_whatever
    def test_all(self,log_mock,execute_mock):
        db = DBClient()
        l = [db.get1,db.get2]
        for function in l:
            function()
            self.assertEqual(3, log_mock.call_count)
            self.assertEqual(3, execute_moock.call_count)
```

The assertion does not get reset in this case. How would I go from here? Should I try something with parameterized tests?

Comment: Yes. Parameterized test (check [ddt](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=2ahUKEwi2h6-pjaXlAhU4RxUIHb1gA_8QFjAAegQICBAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fddt.readthedocs.io%2F&usg=AOvVaw2d9RWWj9C5dfHfEUZfiE5J)), functions can be parameters.

Comment: thanks for the input, that was indeed the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use fixtures for that

```
import pytest


@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def db_client():
    return DBClient()


@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def db_function(request, db_client):
    for func in [db_client.get1, db_client.get2]:
       yield func


@patch_whatever
def test_all(self, log_mock, execute_mock, db_function):
    db_function()
    self.assertEqual(3, log_mock.call_count)
    self.assertEqual(3, execute_mock.call_count)
```